# Is it bad to use UnityContainer in factories?

Tags: .net, unity-container

Have a code:

```
class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public MyFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IMyInterface Create()
    {
        _container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
    }
}
```

I need to resolve IMyInterface using Unity because the interception logic required.
Is it bad to inject Container into a factory?

Comment: I hope not, because I do it too ;). However I normally resolve a concrete class rather than an interface in the `Create` method.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque it is depends on situation, but I prefer do not include container. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common way - yes, it's bad :) Because it looks like [service locator antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/): you pass container and can resolve everything. It's hard to maintain and test this code.

You can implement factory pattern this way:

```
class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    private Func<IMyInterface> _myInterface;

    public MyFactory(Func<IMyInterface> myInterface;)
    {
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    public IMyInterface Create()
    {
        return _myInterface();
    }
}
```

So, your factory does not hold container. And when you inject your factory, unity container will generate Func to resolve your class.

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) in Automatic Factories section.

Comment: This is a fine approach, except when the `Create` method takes parameters to pass to the constructor...